# How to limit cache size gracefully

Tags: python, linux

My tool has a directory for storing cache files. I set the size of the cache to 500G. Before clearing the cache, execute du -sh to determine whether it needs to be cleaned. One problem with this method is that it takes about 15 seconds to execute the du command each time.
Is there any way for me to bypass executing du every time？

Comment: How about having a file with cache metadata, i.e. how much space it currently takes etc, and update it every time you store anything there? In a more advanced version, it could keep each file info with a TTL.

Comment: If you just cleanup without checking if it is actually more than necessary, the worst thing that can happen is that nothing qualifies for deletion. (Evaluating the size of the directory doesn't give you a clue about the single entries. Hence your cleanup should check if the entries can be deleted (aren't currently in use) anyway).